# Server restarting while uploading video or image on VPS - NodeJS Forever

Tags: node.js, file-upload, forever, pm2

I am using nodejitsu's forever package to continuously run my NodeJS(v0.10.28) on VPS. When I tried to upload video or image on server, server stops momentarily and starts again and logging following error:

> error: restarting script because /path/to/uploadDir/d36eafa413c33eb3f02dcd3782e1e77b changed
>   error: forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
>   error: script restart attempt #1

I also tried Unitech's pm2 module, but the same thing is happening.
I am using formidable to upload files to the server. When I try to run my server using command: `node server.js`, all things are working perfectly fine.
I can't figure out what the problem is, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Forever detect files changes on uploading new files and restart your server

Use --watchIgnore parameter to ignore upload folder https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: I tried --watchIgnore but it runs forever just like "node server.js" command, so if I try to logout from SSH, I have to stop forever.

Comment: You need to tell it which directory to ignore and then it will run in the background as expected. For example... "--watchIgnore public/uploads". I'd imagine you could pass the root (/) if you wanted to ignore everything